# Getting namespace of an @XmlType at runtime

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I'm trying to output the `schemaLocation` attribute properly when marshalling an `xjc`-generated class instance. The root element class looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "rootElement"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROOTELEMENT")
public class ROOTELEMENT {
    // Members
}
```

I see there's a `package-info.java` class sitting in the package where all generated classes are, with the following contents:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://my.own.namespace", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package my.generated.classes.package;
```

The answer to [JAXB XJC code generation - “schemaLocation” missing in xml generated by Marshaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161592/851811) proposes setting the  `Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION` property, and it indeed works:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://my.own.namespace my_schema.xsd");
```

But I'd like to avoid typing the namespace, as in:

```
String namespace = getNamespace(rootElementInstance);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, namespace + " my_schema.xsd");
```

I'd appreciate any tips on how to implement the `getNamespace()` function.

---

**EDIT**: I've seen that the `XmlRootElement` and `XmlType` annotations have the `namespace()` method, that seems to be what I'm after (actually, they seem to delegate on the `XmlSchema` provided in `package-info.java`). However, I cannot get an instance of `ROOTELEMENT` casted to any of these types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grab a hand on your package (for example using `ROOTELEMENT.class.getPackage()` if ROOTELEMENT is in the package you want). Then you can simply process it as follow:

```
Package package = // Here retrieve the package;
String namespace = package.getAnnotation(XmlSchema.class).namespace();
...etc...
```

Comment: That worked. Glad to have learnt something new. Thank you. However, I'd expect JAXB to provide a less 'manual' way to achieve this. I'll leave the answer unaccepted for now, in case there's another more elegant option.

Comment: +1 - @XaviLópez - JAXB (JSR-222) currently doesn't offer API to introspect the metadata (maybe it should offer something like JPA does).  The approach give here is probably your best bet.