# JAXB/Jersey - How To Specify "schemaLocation"

Tags: jaxb, jersey

I am using Jersey to create a restful web-service marshals XML.

How would I set the xsi:schemaLocation?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161350/jaxb-xjc-code-generation-schemalocation-missing-in-xml-generated-by-marshall) show how to set the Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION directly on the Marshaller.

The trouble I am having is that Jersey is marshaling the Java objects into XML.  How do I tell Jersey what the schema location is?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `MessageBodyWriter` for this use case.  Through the `ContextResolver` mechanism you can get the `JAXBContext` associated with your domain model.  Then you can get a `Marshaller` from the `JAXBContext` and set the `JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION` on it and do the marshal.

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class FormattingWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>{

    @Context
    protected Providers providers;

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
        WebApplicationException {
        try {
            ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver 
                = providers.getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, mediaType);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            if(null == resolver || null == (jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type))) {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            }
            Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "foo bar");
            m.marshal(object, entityStream);
        } catch(JAXBException jaxbException) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(jaxbException);
        }
    }

    public long getSize(Object t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> One other question. What is the connection between the my rest resource and the provider?

You still implement your resource the same way.  The `MessageBodyWriter` mechanism is just a way to override how the writing to XML will be done.  The `@Provider` annotation is a signal to the JAX-RS application to have this class automatically registered.

> My resource class would return a `Foo` object.  I take it I should be implementing a
>   `MessageBodyWriter<Foo>`?

You could implement it as `MessageBodyWriter<Foo>` if you only want it applied to the `Foo` class.  If you want it to apply to more than just `Foo` you can implement to the `isWriteable` method to return true for the appropriate classes.