# Best way to configure the output XML version for jaxb via resteasy on jboss

Tags: java, xml, jboss, jaxb, resteasy

I have data that I'm serializing that has characters that aren't allowed in xml version 1.0:

```
<value>this &#18; is not good for 1.0</value>
```

When RESTEasy serializes this via JAXB it produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<value>this &#18; is not good for 1.0</value>
```

Which XML parsers will not parse as 1.0 does not allow that character, if I set the xml version to 1.1 parsers are happy.

I can do this via:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.1");
```

So what I'm wanting to know is what's the best way to configure jboss / resteasy / jaxb such that when it creates the transformer it uses that it's configured with this output property.

Comment: A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will typically not create a `Transformer`.  Are you looking to influence the XML output by the JAXB impl.

Comment: @Blaise Good to know, do you know of a good reference for how to lookup this sort of configuration?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the following on the `Marshaller` to create a new header.

```
    // Remove the header that JAXB will generate
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

    // Grab the encoding that will be used for Marshalling
    String encoding = (String) marshaller.getProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING);

    // Specify the new header
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.1\" encoding=\"" + encoding + "\">");
```

In a JAX-RS environment you can create a `MessageBodyWriter` to configure a `Marshaller` this way.  The following answer to a similar question includes an example of how to do this:

- [JAXB/Jersey - How To Specify "schemaLocation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572526/jaxb-jersey-how-to-specify-schemalocation/16572623#16572623)

Comment: This is good but I'm wanting to configure resteasy such that it does this by default rather than hand code this for every API entry point.

Comment: @Tom - I'm not sure you can.  However you could create one `MessageBodyWriter` class that would work with many different services.

Comment: I got this to work in the standalone case but had to change the property set to "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.xmlHeaders" (note the internal). I still haven't figured out how to get this into the marshaller for resteasy.

Comment: Thanks Tom and Blaise ... the best thing to do seems to be to cover both bases as outlined here: http://timepassguys.blogspot.com/2011/12/jaxb-exception-javaxxmlbindpropertyexce.html ...and this diff from a jersey framework commit also seems to follow this best-practice for sniffing out the right xmlheader key: https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/commits/archive/2011-03/message/33