# Multiple XSD schemas in one xjc/JAXB generated XML file?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, xjc

I've got a set of XSD schema files I'm generating Java classes from:

http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch.xsd

http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/forms/ReturnofAllotmentShares-v3-0.xsd

http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/forms/FormSubmission-v2-11.xsd

These come together to form a single XML document I need to submit to the Companies House XML Gateway. Right now, the XML files generated from the Java files generated by `xjc` from these schemas do not include schemaLocation or other schema-related information. By  following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161350/jaxb-xjc-code-generation-schemalocation-missing-in-xml-generated-by-marshall) I'm able to add a top-level `schemaLocation` to the `<GovTalkMessage>` element, but not to the others (e.g. `<FormSubmission>` and `<ReturnofAllotmentShares>`.

Is there a way I can do this, or to set it at Java-class generation time?

EDIT: Error returned when I remove one of the schemaLocation attributes (if I include it, it returns successfully)

```
<GovTalkErrors>
    <Error>
        <RaisedBy>CH_XML_Gateway</RaisedBy>
        <Number>100</Number>
        <Type>fatal</Type>
        <Text>XML failed schema validation: Invalid XML: Unknown element 'ReturnofAllotmentShares'  line 36 column 86</Text>
        <Location></Location>
    </Error>
</GovTalkErrors>
```

My understanding is that without the `schemaLocation` attribute, the parser doesn't know what specific document we're referring to here. Each document (maybe 20 of them) is it's own XML schema.

Comment: Are you sure that the schemaLocation attribute is _required_ by the Companies House XML Gateway? That would be unusual, in my experience.

Comment: @kimbert it would seem so, without it I receive invalid schema errors

Comment: Please edit your answer and quote the 'schema error', accurately and in full.